# Always on VPN profile with Group policy

Tags: vpn, group-policy

I am trying to deploy the always on VPN profile via GPO, with a powershell script from Richard hicks. the script works when i run local, but i can't figure out how to run it with a startup script in group policy.

have anyone figured this out ? Intune or SCCM is not a possibility

Edit: Solved
Thanks to Richard
I got it to work now, i used you suggestion and remote signed the script, then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this more than a few times. :) It should work as long as you place the script and XML files somewhere reachable on the network (I usually put them in SYSVOL) and you use the -AllUserConnection switch when you run the script.

Here's an example from my lab:

Script Name: \\lab.example.net\SysVol\lab.example.net\scripts\New-AovpnConnection.ps1

Script Parameters: -xmlFilePath \\lab.example.net\SYSVOL\lab.example.net\scripts\ProfileXML.xml -AllUserConnection

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: That is also what i am trying, do you run it in computer context in the GPO setting. our users are not local admins.

Can it be the execution policy that makes it not run ?

Comment: Computer Configuration (Enabled)
Policies
Windows Settings
Scripts
Startup
For this GPO, Script order: Not configuredName Parameters 
\\example.local\NETLOGON\New-AovpnConnection.ps1 -xmlFilePath \\example.local\NETLOGON\ProfileXML.xml -AllUserConnection

Comment: I get Errorcode 1 - Incorrect function when i look in the event viewer of my test machine.

Comment: You're probably better off using Group Policy to copy those files locally, and execute the startup script using the local file.

Comment: @PawPedersen Yes, assign the startup script to the computer. It will run in the SYSTEM context which requires the -AllUserConnection parameter for my script. And yes, you may also need to add -ExecutionPolicy Byass to the Script Name example above if you haven't enabled RemoteSigned or something else via GPO previously.

Comment: @GregAskew I've had no issues running the script from SYSVOL as my example shows, but copying locally would work as well.